# Return proper on first iteration, improper on anything more, java

Tags: java, return, substring, comparison

I'm stil learning java so i could have missed something here, but it does not look like i did, and its doing something funky i can't pin down. 
I'm prompting the user for an arithmatic operator or 'q' to quit. When i run the prog to test it, it works right if i enter a valid input the first time, but if i try to go 1 or more invalid input, the return always defaults to the last character in the check string even if it stops running and goes to return before it gets to the end.

```
//gets operation from user
public static String getOperation(Scanner scan) {
//valid input string to check against
    String ops = "+-*/=Q";
    System.out.print("Please enter an operation (+, -, /, *, = or Q to quit): ");
    String op = scan.next();
//makes sure input is only 1 character
    if (op.length() > 1) {
//recurses if not 1 character
        getOperation(scan);
    }
    op = op.toUpperCase();
    String check = "";
//begins substringing the check string one at a time for comparison against valid
    for (int i = 0; i < ops.length(); i++) {
        if (i == ops.length() - 1) {
            check = ops.substring(i);
        } else {
            check = ops.substring(i, i + 1);
        }
//exits with current check if appropriate character
        if (check.equals(op)) {
            return op;
        }
    }
//if not valid input, recurses for proper input
    getOperation(scan);
    return check;
}
```

When testing if i enter '/' the first time, it returns '/'.
When testing if i enter 'a', 's', 'd', '/' it returns 'Q', should be '/'

Comment: Can you give a sample input with expected sample output?

Comment: You make a recursive call, but you don't use what you've already read in that call, and you don't use the result. It's unclear what you intend to do, but that is dubious.

Comment: Thank you for your insights!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the correct way to use recursion.  Let's assume a very basic invalid input: 'a', '/'.

When the function reads 'a', it will progress completely through the for loop, and when the for loop ends, `check` will be equal to `"Q"` because that's what the last operation in the for loop will always do.  Then, it will recurse:

```
//if not valid input, recurses for proper input
    getOperation(scan);
    return check;
```

and read a valid input `'/'`.  The second level of the function will return '/', BUT, this result is discarded because you do not assign the output of the recursion to anything.  The function then returns check, which will be equal to `'Q'` for all invalid inputs (because it's the last value in the ops string).

So, the solution is to `return getOperation(scan);` instead of calling the function then discarding the output.

A few other notes:

- Use `ops.charAt(i)` instead of `ops.substring()` because you are only interested in a single character at a time.  This further means you can:
- Use the primitive `==` to compare, which saves you a function call (this requires `op` to be a `char`, but you should do this anyways because again, you are only interested in a single character at a time. Or, an even better idea:
- Instead of your own for loop, use the `ops.contains(op)` function; if it returns true, then return `op` directly, otherwise you know that the input is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Clayton handled the explanation of why you are not using recursion here correctly well so I will show you how to remove all of the recursion from your code, because you should not be using it here at all.

Here is an example below of I want I think you want your code to be doing (though you did not include much info on what exactly you want it to do.)

```
public static String getOperation(Scanner scan) {
    //valid input string to check against
    String ops = "+-*/=";

    while (true)
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter a valid operation (+, -, /, *, = or Q to quit): ");
        String op = scan.next();
        op = op.toUpperCase();
        if (ops.contains(op) && op.length() == 1)
        {
            return op;
        }
        else if (op.equals("Q"))
        {
            return "User quit early and did not return an operation.";
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how the recursion is all removed and `Q` is gone from the ops to check since it has a unique case.  This will prompt the user forever until they enter a valid operation and will return a *single* operation once they finally enter a valid one.

In addition if they choose to quit, no operation is returned because they did not enter a valid one!  So I just returned a `String` that explains what happened, though you can do anything you want in this scenario of course.

Additionally I added the `op.length() == 1` check to the `if` statement rather than making a separate `if` that checks if the `String` is larger than 1 character.

Example Run:

> Please enter a valid operation (+, -, /, *, = or Q to quit): asd
>
> Please enter a valid operation (+, -, /, *, = or Q to quit): +-=
>
> Please enter a valid operation (+, -, /, *, = or Q to quit): +
>
> Returns: +

Comment: That is far simpler than i was trying to do, tank you for your knowledge! it does exactly what i was trying to do

Comment: @Pedro Emmo-Ecks No problem, glad I was able to assume what you were trying to do!  In the future really try to figure out a solution without using recursion, you will _rarely_ ever need recursion over a loop.

Comment: Noted. It's just that I'm still learning through the Microsoft Academy courses on edX, and recursion was recently covered, and i'm pretty sure we were encouraged to use it where we can.  We were given a basic understanding of how recursion works, and basically to use it for code that needs to be repeated, so i thought "Hey, this needs to be repeated if it's invalid, recursion!" Thank you for explaining a little more.